# A/B testing views in the appstore?

Tags: iphone, ios, testing

Does anyone has experience with releasing an app that loads a different ViewController for the same functionality with a switch. So 50% of users always use one version and 50% the other. [There is a good description here] http://littlebigthinkers.com/post/how-to-run-ab-tests-in-ios-apps. Is this somehow violates Apple TOS.

Answer (score 3):

That would definitely be fine if that the two viewcontrollers provide the same functionality. Even if did different things, you'd most likely be ok so long as users A and B have access to everything as described in the description and screenshots etc.
You do risk confusing your users though, so I'd be a little careful here. If an A user talks to a B user about your app or posts screenshots etc you could get confusion, or worse complaints and bad reviews.

For example: Why does my app not do COOL THING when my mate's copy does?

Comment: Some one passionately engaging with my product. That would be a great problem to have! :) Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked on apps that implemented very significant A/B tests (not just small UI differences, but enabling / disabling big features), and it was never a problem with Apple.

If anyone's curious, I built this framework to do it: https://github.com/mindsnacks/MSActiveConfig

Answer (score 0):

Arise.io is providing a framework which does A/B testing for iOS, so I am pretty sure that Apple is "ok" with this practice even if it is not official.

Answer (score 0):

Appiterate has a WYSIWYG editor to A/B test different versions of a screen for both iOS and Android.